# column value shifts with Expand / collapse in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have created a report in ssrs. The values in column named 3 will be getting expanded whenever I press the (+) sign on the customer column. But before expanding, the column 3 will not have any values so all the values from the nearby columns get shifted one column to the left as in the below image.

To be more specific, **the value of the right most column got shifted to one column left before expand**. How can we prevent this?

[image]

Comment: If no value set "       "

Comment: Thank you.. it works! @Snowlockk